# How to keep the same path for development and production

Tags: javascript, html

In development mode I access a page in my application as: `http://localhost:8080/myapp/color/edit` The same page is accessed in production as `http://www.myapp.com/color/edi`

In one of my elements I use the following to POST to the server:

`data-url="/red/edit"`

When in development, the above turns to `http://localhost:8080/red/edit` and in production it turns to `http://www.myapp.com/red/edit`. So it would work in production but not locally.

**Question**

How should I put the POST url in `data-url` so that the POST url becomes `http://localhost:8080/myapp/color/edit` in development and `http://www.myapp.com/color/edit` in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `baseUrl` variable and toggle it based on your environment. You can check the `window.location` value to see which environment your app is being accessed in.

**Production:**

```
var baseUrl = "";
```

**Development:**

```
var baseUrl = "/myapp";
```

Then, define your `data-url` property using the `baseUrl`

```
var dataUrl = baseUrl + "/red/edit";
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your app is built, you can and an `ENV` variable and have the url change based on if you are running a dev or production environment. ie `data-url=ENVURL + "/color/edit"` or some environments (such as rails) have link handlers to handle the switching for you.

the simple way to do it in JS would be to use `window.location.hostname` to return the current host:

```js
var host = window.location.hostname;
var el = TARGET ELEMENT

el.dataset.url = "http://" + host + "/your/post/path";
```